# npx create-react-app my-app yield result 'create-react-app' is not recognized

Tags: reactjs, react-native, frontend, create-react-app

I tried to use the **'npx create-react app [project name]'** in my project folder but it produced this error

[image]

This happened after I **deleted the create-react-app.cmd** in my **C:\Users[myname]\AppData\Roaming\npm** folder.

I deleted the file because I had a different problem before where I used the same command but produced "module not found". So someone suggested me to delete the create-react-app.cmd file in my roaming/npm folder. even before doing this, I have tried uninstalling global create-react-app based on the create react app repo.

So was the deletion of create-react-app.cmd the cause to my problem? if so, what should I do to have that file back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

npx came with NPM, so with nodejs.

Uninstall and reinstall nodejs will fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add `npm i create-react-app` command before that command, and it will fix the problem.